# Twitter4j returning formatted source of tweet

Tags: twitter4j

I have a question, I am trying to format the source form where the tweets of users on my timeline is coming from using twitter4j, and a application I am developing.

this is the code I am using

```
appNameText.setText(status.getSource());
```

I have it positioned, but it is returning the full address of the source like this

> < a href="http://blackberry.com/twitter" rel="nofloow">Twitter for Blackberry

and all I want is it to say for instance Twitter for blackberry

Comment: Try `status.getText();`

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the String Class in the BlackBerry JDE API, and visualise what you can do with e.g. the indexOf and substring methods. (Though you don't state as such, I am guessing that you are developing in Java for a BlackBerry, but the same applies in other development scenarios)

Comment: No I am using Java for Android and twitter4j.

Comment: O.K. I was mis-led by your frequent references to BlackBerry.  I just took a quick look at the String class in the Android API (java.lang.String), and it would appear to have the same methods (not unsurprisingly).  So my answer still holds I think?